# File to import not found or unreadable: normalize

Tags: css

```
$ sudo scss scss/custom.scss css/custom.css
```

when i am trying to run scss command i am getting this error :

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: normalize.
        on line 13 of base/_init.scss
        from line 33 of custom.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Please help me out to solve this error.

Comment: " Use --trace for backtrace."

Comment: Why are you running it with `sudo`?  Please [edit]  your question and explain exactly what you're trying to do, and where you got these instructions from.

Comment: I use --trace but not getting anything